# Android parse facebook login not working after using facebook graph api to share link.

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I have an Android app with parse login with Facebook that works just fine… I´m building a new version of the app in which the app has the capability to do share to a Facebook Page, as the page. This is my code:

this is the code to request the list of pages the user manages

```
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions, publish_pages, manage_pages,user_about_me");
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity,PERMISSIONS);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

    new Request(
             session,
             "/me/accounts",
             null,
             HttpMethod.GET,
             new Request.Callback() {
             public void onCompleted(Response response) {
             /* handle the result */}
```

Once selected a page, the  link share is done by:

```
    final String id = json_obj.getString("id");
    String token = json_obj.getString("access_token");
    Date date = new Date(3600);
    List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions, publish_pages, manage_pages,user_about_me");

    final Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", message);
    params.putString("access_token", token);
    params.putString("link", link);
    params.putString("picture", image);

    new Request(
          session,
          "/" + id + "/feed",
          params,
          HttpMethod.POST,
          new Request.Callback() {
          public void onCompleted(Response response) {
          /* handle the result */}
```

The code works just fine, the link is posted to a Facebook Page, as the facebook page.

The problem comes when the user logs off and tries to log back in with facebook. Parse log in fails, without error message, and returns a null user. The weird thing is that this keeps on happening the particular device where the code was run, matter what user tries to login, or even if we uninstall the app and install a previous version which was working perfectly.

So far I’ve tested with three different devices and I get the same result, everything works fine before doing the facebook share as page. After that, no matter what user or what version of the app I run, the parse facebook log in fails returning a null user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the what the issue WAS...

They way I had the code, it would ask for facebook permissions several times, and that would somehow mess up the user on facebook